# How can I pretty-print a data member char array as a string (as in boost::static_string) with lldb?

Tags: boost, lldb

I am trying to define a custom summary for Boosts `static_string` class template. Example source file:

```
#include <boost/static_string/static_string.hpp>

const boost::static_string<5> s{"abc"};
```

Without any formatters, `frame variable -R s` gives me

```
(boost::static_strings::static_string<5>) s = {
  boost::static_strings::detail::static_string_base<5, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > = {
    size_ = '\x03'
    data_ = {
      [0] = 'a'
      [1] = 'b'
      [2] = 'c'
      [3] = '\0'
      [4] = '\0'
      [5] = '\0'
    }
  }
}
```

I get very close with the builtin formatting for zero-terminated C-strings, i.e., `frame variable -f s &s.data_`:

```
(boost::static_strings::detail::static_string_base<...>::value_type (*)[6]) &data_ = "abc"
```

but trying to automate that with

```
type summary add -x "^boost::static_strings::static_string<.+>$" --summary "${&var.data_%s}"
```

doesn't work (also tried `"${var.&data_%s}"`) - the custom format string cannot be parsed. According to the [docs](http://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#id3), an indirection `*var` works with the special `var` placeholder, but `&` doesn't seem to work (it's also not mentioned in the docs, so that was a wild guess).

Answer (score 0):

The python API can be of help here. For summary strings, you can register a custom python function that returns the desired output. This function accepts an instance of `SBValue` (and some internal dictionary that you shouldn't touch). Exemplary `boost.py`:

```
import lldb

def staticStringSummary(valobj, unused):
    data = valobj.GetChildMemberWithName('data_')
    err = lldb.SBError()
    string = data.GetData().GetString(err, 0)
    return string

def __lldb_init_module(debugger, internalDict):
    debugger.HandleCommand('type summary add -x "^boost::static_strings::static_string<.+>$" -F boost.staticStringSummary')
```

If you load the above file in a (possibly project-local) `.lldbinit` as

```
command script import path/to/boost.py
```

for the above example, `fr v` will yield

```
(boost::static_strings::static_string<5>) s = abc
```

Note that Boost's `static_string` class makes sure there is always a zero-byte at the end, which makes sure this solution works. Not sure whether this is the best approach, though (I came up with it while formulating the question).